# gcc likely() unlikely() macros and assembly code

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to see how gcc's `likely()` and `unlikely()` branch prediction macros has effect on assembly code. In the following piece of code I don't see any difference in the generated assembly code regardless of which macro i use. Any pointers on what's happening?

```
  0  int main() {
  1     volatile int x;
  2     unlikely(x)?x++:x--;
  3 }
```

Asm code:

```
  0 0000000000000014 <main>:
  1 int main() {
  2   14:   55                      push   rbp
  3   15:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4     volatile int x;
  5     likely(x)?x++:x--;
  6   18:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  7   1b:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
  8   1d:   0f 95 c0                setne  al
  9   20:   0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
 10   23:   48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
 11   26:   74 0b                   je     33 <main+0x1f>
 12   28:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
 13   2b:   83 c0 01                add    eax,0x1
 14   2e:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
 15   31:   eb 09                   jmp    3c <main+0x28>
 16   33:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
 17   36:   83 e8 01                sub    eax,0x1
 18   39:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
 19 }
 20   3c:   5d                      pop    rbp
 21   3d:   c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you compiled without optimization.  [Basic block reordering](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/news/reorder.html) is an optimization, so without it, `__builtin_expect` does not have this effect.  With optimization, I observe that the sense of the branch is inverted when switching the expected result.

Note that whether this has any effect on current x86 processors is difficult to say.

Comment: On x86 unlikely has an effect of slowing down the code, read here: https://johnysswlab.com/how-branches-influence-the-performance-of-your-code-and-what-can-you-do-about-it/